# How to change UIPickerView title text color based on position

Tags: swift, colors, uipickerview, selected

I want to set an UIPickerView so that the title of the row that is selected (in the center) is blue, and the two rows above and below have text color black, and the others color gray..

so it will look something like this

[image]

is there any way to do this in swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Below example is for one component.

```
var pickerArray = [String]()
var selectedRow: Int {
    return pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    pickerView.reloadComponent(component)
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
    var color = UIColor.gray

    if row == selectedRow {
        color = UIColor.blue
    } else if selectedRow == row - 1 || selectedRow == row + 1 {
        color = UIColor.black
    }

    return NSAttributedString(string: pickerArray[row], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color])
}
```

Maybe it exists another way, but I think this will be sufficient :]

// Update1: NOT RECOMMENDED

You could override (hitTest:point:event) and return self from it and then reload the components on (touchesMoved:touches:event). BUT the scroll and touches on the picker will not work. You will need to do something else :(

// Update2: The result:
[image]

Comment: what I was looking for is changing color while scrolling but I guess that is impossible with the APi we are given with UIPickerView.. But thanks for the response!

Comment: see my update. Maybe you will have more luck then I had making it to work :]

Comment: by the way, my NSattributedString's font part is not working do you have any clue why?

Comment: hmm, strange. I added a screenshot of the result

Comment: do you use:

   `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
       return pickerArray[row]
    }`

Comment: the color changes fine. But NSString.Key.font would not work.. Maybe they block changing font in the inner systems of UIPickerView

Answer (score 1):

@Deryck Lucian **update answer**:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let pickerLabel = UILabel()
        pickerLabel.textColor = (row == pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: component)) ? UIColor.red : UIColor.green
        pickerLabel.text = List[row]
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        return pickerLabel
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        pickerView.reloadComponent(component)

    }
```